# How to get data in a column in order by using SQL in operator

Tags: sql, select, where-clause, in-operator

There is a data set as shown below;

[image]

When input for event_type is 4, 1, 2, 3 for example, I would like to get 3, 999, 3, 9 from cnt_stamp in this order. I created a SQL code as shown below, but it seems like it always returns 999, 3, 9, 3 regardless the order of the input.
How can I fix the SQL to achieve this? Thank you for taking your time, and please let me know if you have any question.

```
SELECT `cnt_stamp` FROM `stm_events` WHERE `event_type` in (4,1,2,3)
```

Comment: While it would be strange to do, you could use UNION as in SELECT * FROM stm_events WHERE event_type = 4 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM stm_events WHERE event_type = 1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM stm_events WHERE event_type = 2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM stm_events WHERE event_type = 3 - However this looks bad.

Comment: @NoChance this might be the only way to achieve it...

Comment: My above SELECT is a bit risky since it depends on the sequence of SELECT statements. Also  there is no guarantee that the db will necessarily follow the order of SELECT statements when it presents the result. The only way to guarantee order in result is to use SORT BY, so the above solution may work, but is NOT guaranteed to always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ORDER BY FIELD(event_type, 4, 1, 2, 3) in your query. It should look like:

```
SELECT cnt_stamp FROM stm_events WHERE event_type in (4,1,2,3) ORDER BY FIELD(event_type, 4, 1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score -1):

its cannot because as default the data sort by ascending, if u want result like u want,, better u create 1 column for indexing

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I would like to achieve this without adding a new column...